# How to print all the elements of a specific column from a table from database in custom module?

Tags: 7, database

I have a  custom module. I would like to see all the blocks in it . For that i have written a query in my costom.module file . But it will show me the following error.

```
Query:-

 $result = db_query('SELECT *FROM  `block` ORDER BY
`block`.`delta` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30');
 while ($node = db_fetch_object($result)) {
 print_r("$result");
 }
```

Why this is not working, Where am i going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made 4 errors:

1. You should use {} around table names, not ``.
2. print_r does not like objects Drupal uses, for testing purposes it's way better to use

   while($row = $result->fetchAssoc() ){
   }
3. $node may be already used elsewhere, it's not wise to use common names if you don't mean it.
4. `SELECT *FROM` should be `SELECT * FROM` (kudos for Clive)

Comment: 4. `SELECT *FROM ` should be `SELECT * FROM `